# How do I manipulate python numpy values in a separate C++ plugin

Tags: c++, numpy

I'm trying to send the data of a numpy array in Python to a separate C++ plugin.

Is it correct to just send the address I get from __array_interface__['data'][0]  to a C++ plugin, and create a double pointer from it there? I'm assuming that since it's a flattened array, all the values are aligned without any gaps.

So I've got some code that works in about 50 cases, then if I run it more often, it becomes unstable and the values become extremely high, like he would shift some memory locations slightly, and eventually it crashes.

in Python:

```
aWeights = np.zeros(100, dtype='float64')
aWeights.fill(0.33)
iDataAddress = aWeights.__array_interface__['data'][0]
```

then I'm sending iDataAddress to C++, and I'm creating a double pointer from it:

```
unsigned long int iDataAddress = [code for getting the iAddressFromPython];
double * array = (double*)iDataAddress;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    MGlobal::DisplayInfo(array[i])
```

If I run those 2 parts about 50 times, it's all good. After about 50 times it starts to inconsistently log wrong values. These values become exponentially high. It looks to me like he's shifting some memory location, meaning in memory the array may not perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `ndarray` object itself to the extension function and use the C version of the [NumPy array interface](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.interface.html), if not the [standardized interface](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3118/) inspired thereby.  This avoids the possibility of crashing Python with invalid input from a script.

Regardless of how you access the array layout, the answer is *no*: you do have to consider the strided case, which is presumably what is causing the misbehavior you observe.  There are also more complicated cases depending on the interface, like indirect buffer objects and [pointer-based multidimensional arrays](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliffe_vector).  You could of course merely detect and reject such arrays, which is safe if not full-featured.

Comment: Do you mean \__array_struct__? The content of that attribute keeps changing, when I call it a few times, without changing anything in the array

Comment: @Tom: Yes, that’s the NumPy C interface, despite it being a Python attribute.  What do you mean by “content”?  The attribute value is probably created on lookup, but the `PyArrayInterface` members will be equal each time.

Comment: ah, I see. So I got it to C++ now, and was able to read the first item of the data. But getting the strides troubles me now and I can't find any info about it on the net. I've got this:
PyArrayInterface * interf = (PyArrayInterface*)iAddressFromPython; 
Py_intptr_t * stridesPtr = interf->strides; 
fprint(sterr, "stride: %u, stridesPtr[0]); // so the print either gives me very large number or crashes

Comment: @Tom: You shouldn’t be casting any pointers.  Pass the array itself into C, then call `PyObject_GetAttrString(a,"__array_struct__")` and `PyCObject_AsVoidPtr` on the result.  See if that finds any bugs.

Comment: In C++, you’ll still need a `static_cast` on the `void*` you get.  But it’s not a `reinterpret_cast` like your (inadvisable) C-style cast!